# MySql Date_sub and DATEDIFF not Working for timestamp time() in integer Field

Tags: mysql, sql, time, datediff

i got a problem with MySQL Date_SUB AND DATEDIFF(). I wrote the timestamp with php time() into a integer Field. The queries below are not working.

```
tmstmp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

OR

```
tmstmp between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE()
```

OR

```
tmstmp > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

Where is the error?

(sry for my bad english)

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: i get no results the tmstmp = 1469448868 (f.e)

Answer (score 1):

All these statements are working fine.

```
set @tmstmp = '2017-01-29';

[in] select @tmstmp > (now() - interval 1 day);
[out] 0
[in] select @tmstmp between (curdate() - interval 1 month ) and curdate();
[out] 1
[in] select @tmstmp > date_sub(curdate(), interval 15 day);
[out] 1
```

Comment: tmstmp = 1469448868;   written with php time() into an integer field